# Laravel-excel export date format is different in excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I have an export function and when I `die` the results. It is

```
  {
    "outsourcer": "ＮＳ＆Ｃ㈱",
    "manager_name": "安楽",
    "worker_name": "吉田邦広",
    "sesnum1": "MS-JAN-",
    "sesnum2": 1,
    "start": "2021/10/29",
    "work": "TEST作業１",
    "cost": 765000,
    "worktime_l": "140",
    "worktime_h": "180",
    "cost_add": 1000,
    "cost_trip": "7000",
    "cost_trip_terms": "泊数換算",
    "cost_midnight": 3000,
    "cost_reduced": 0,
    "end_date": "2022/03/31",
    "end": "2022/03/31",
    "quarter": "年度2022 1Q",
    "reserve1": "",
    "reserve2": "",
    "working_period": "6か月"
  },
```

But when I view it in excel, the date format are different. it became d/m/Y

[image]

In my response I did to parse the date to the specific format but in excel it returns different

```
          $d->start = Carbon::parse($d->start)->format('Y/m/d');
            $d->end = Carbon::parse($d->end)->format('Y/m/d');
            $d->end_date = Carbon::parse($d->end_date)->format('Y/m/d');
```

Here is my query for getting the data

```
    public function collection()
    {
        // dd('here');
        $sesWorker = SesWorker::where('ses_id',1)->get()->toArray();

        foreach ($sesWorker as $d){
            $sesWorkers = DB::table('ses_contracts')
            ->join('ses_worker','ses_contracts.id','ses_worker.ses_id')
            ->join('corporates','corporates.id','ses_contracts.outsourcer')
            ->join('workers','workers.id','ses_worker.worker_name')
            ->select([
                'corporates.corpname as outsourcer',
                'ses_contracts.outsourcer_manager_name as manager_name',
                'workers.name as worker_name',
                'ses_worker.sesnum1 as sesnum1',
                'ses_worker.sesnum2 as sesnum2',
                'ses_contracts.work_date1 as start',
                'ses_contracts.workname as work',
                'ses_worker.cost as cost',
                'ses_worker.worktime_l as worktime_l',
                'ses_worker.worktime_h as worktime_h',
                'ses_worker.cost_add as cost_add',
                'ses_worker.cost_trip as cost_trip',
                'ses_worker.cost_trip_terms as cost_trip_terms',
                'ses_worker.cost_midnight as cost_midnight',
                'ses_worker.cost_reduced as cost_reduced',
                'ses_worker.end_date as end_date',
                'ses_contracts.id as ses_id'
            ])
            ->selectRaw('GREATEST(ses_contracts.work_date1, ses_contracts.work_date2, ses_contracts.work_date3, ses_contracts.work_date4, ses_contracts.work_date5, ses_contracts.work_date6) as end')
            ->selectRaw('GREATEST(ses_contracts.work_date1, ses_contracts.work_date2, ses_contracts.work_date3, ses_contracts.work_date4, ses_contracts.work_date5, ses_contracts.work_date6) as quarter')
           
           
            ->get();

        }

        foreach ($sesWorkers as $d){
            
            $working_period =  DB::select('
            SELECT SUM((ses_contracts.work_date1!="") + (ses_contracts.work_date2!="") 
            + (ses_contracts.work_date3!="") + (ses_contracts.work_date4!="") + (ses_contracts.work_date5!="") + (ses_contracts.work_date6!="")) as working_period
            from ses_contracts
            where id = '.$d->ses_id);
            $d->reserve1 = "";
            $d->reserve2 = "";
            $d->quarter = '年度'.Carbon::parse($d->quarter)->format('Y').' '.Carbon::parse($d->quarter)->quarter.'Q';
            
            $d->working_period = $working_period[0]->working_period.'か月';

            $d->start = Carbon::parse($d->start)->format('Y/m/d');
            $d->end = Carbon::parse($d->end)->format('Y/m/d');
            $d->end_date = Carbon::parse($d->end_date)->format('Y/m/d');
            unset($d->ses_id);
        }
        
        
        // die($sesWorkers);
        return $sesWorkers;
    }
```

I used this package https://laravel-excel.com/

Can someone tell me what did i miss? thanks in advance

Comment: try formatting https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#dates

Comment: i still ccoudnt get the solution @JohnLobo

Comment: @draw134 I am not sure, but I think Excel uses its own date formatting when you apply date formatting to column. Try to format column as text and add date to it. It may work, but sorting may not work properly if you do this.

Comment: where do you mean to format excel? when after importing? What i want is it is formatted automatically when exporting. @RaviPatel

Comment: First try to do it shown [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#formatting-columns). If it doesn't work, then format every column as a string in your code by disabling intelligent formatting, as shown [here](Disable intelligent formatting).

Comment: can you help me implementing it? @RaviPatel. Im having a hard time. Can I post my code?

Comment: @draw134 Sorry, It won't be possible to help with the code, but you can clearly see what you have to do in [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html#formatting-columns). Implement WithColumnFormatting on your export class and add columnFormats function to the class. In columnFormats function you will be able to assign each column format as shown in the docs.